# How to make post request to server from JavaScript

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, http-post

In my solution I have a controller with the name OrdersController.It implements few methods and one of them is :

```
[HttpPost]
private void DeleteAllOrders( bool deleteOrNot)
{
  //something
}
```

and I have .js file that describes the click event of an element and I'd like to make a post to theat controller's(/Orders/DeleteAllOrders) method from the java script.

```
$("#clear-all-orders").click(function () {

        var urlToTheControllerMethod = "/Orders/DeleteAllOrders";

        $.post(urlToTheControllerMethod, true);

    });
```

Comment: An advice,use `Jquery` for simplicity and compatibility.

Comment: As you can see that is what I am actually using.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see, you're using asp.net mvc on your server. You have to change the visibility modifier to `public` to expose the method.

```
[HttpPost]
public void DeleteAllOrders( bool deleteOrNot)
{
  //something
}
```